# Как отсортировать метки в зависимости от города yandex map?

Tags: javascript, json, yandex-maps-api

Вывожу метки из json на карту, но не понимаю как их отсортировать, то есть я кликаю на "метки Томска", должен открыться город Томск и только его метки должны показаться на карте, а остальные скрыться. Выбор города и перемещение карты я вроде реализовал и область видимости даже нашел (bounds), но вот с метками не понимаю как работать

```js
const dataJSON = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 1, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.863338, 37.565466]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 1, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.763338, 37.565466]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 3, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.744522, 37.616378]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
        {"type": "Feature", "id": 4, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.780898, 37.642889]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
      {"type": "Feature", "id": 5, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [56.53363798123554,84.98842349999994]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}}
    ]
}


ymaps.ready(init);

function init () {
    let myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.76, 37.64],
            zoom: 10
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
            // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
            clusterize: true,
            // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
            gridSize: 32,
            clusterDisableClickZoom: true,
        });

    objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#redClusterIcons');
    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

    objectManager.add(dataJSON);
  
  $('[data-city]').click(function() {
        const city = $(this).attr('data-city');
        ymaps.geocode(city, {
            results: 1
        }).then(function(res) {
            const firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);
            const bounds = firstGeoObject.properties.get('boundedBy');

            myMap.setBounds(bounds, {
                checkZoomRange: true
            })
        })
    });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-city="Томск">Выбрать метки Томска</div>
<div data-city="Москва">Выбрать метки Москвы</div>

<div class="map">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если знать координаты города и радиус круга, в который "попадает" весь город - можно выбрать точки, которые в такой круг попадут.

Можно воспользоваться формулой `(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 <= R^2`, где `x`, `y` - координаты точки, `a`, `b` - координаты центра круга `R` - радиус круга.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А есть возможность в массив "features" добавить новый ключ/значение?

```
"city" : "tomsk"
"city" : "moscow"
```

Если есть, то дальше будет легко, если нет, то только по координатам города (но для этого они должны быть заданы)

```
const dataJSON = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {"city": "tomsk", "type": "Feature", "id": 1, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.863338, 37.565466]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
    {"city": "tomsk","type": "Feature", "id": 1, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.763338, 37.565466]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
    {"city": "moscow","type": "Feature", "id": 3, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.744522, 37.616378]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
    {"city": "moscow","type": "Feature", "id": 4, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [55.780898, 37.642889]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}},
    {"city": "tomsk","type": "Feature", "id": 5, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [56.53363798123554,84.98842349999994]}, "properties": {"balloonContentHeader": "<font size=3><b><a target='_blank' href='https://yandex.ru'>Здесь может быть ваша ссылка</a></b></font>", "balloonContentBody": "<p>Ваше имя: <input name='login'></p><p><em>Телефон в формате 2xxx-xxx:</em>  <input></p><p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></p>", "balloonContentFooter": "<font size=1>Информация предоставлена: </font> <strong>этим балуном</strong>", "clusterCaption": "<strong><s>Еще</s> одна</strong> метка", "hintContent": "<strong>Текст  <s>подсказки</s></strong>"}}
]} 

const markerTomsk = dataJSON.features.filter(p => p.city.includes("tomsk"))
console.log(markerTomsk)
```